# How to load a form to django base template using inclusion tag avoiding RecursionError?

Tags: python, django

I have already tried to use inclusion tag in many ways like seperating the html file and including it in base template(layout.html) or even directly on the base template(layout.html), I keep getting
RecursionError at /
maximum recursion depth exceeded

In app/forms.py

```
class UserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserSettings
    fields = ['theme_color','text_color']
    widgets = {
        'theme_color':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'text_color':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    }
    error_messages = {
        NON_FIELD_ERRORS : {
            'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
        }
    }
```

In app/templatetags/theme.py

```
@register.inclusion_tag('layout.html')
def settings_form():
    set_form = UserSettingsForm()
    return {'set_form':set_form}
```

In layout.html

```
{% load theme %}
...
<form action="{% url 'set_settings' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}}
   {% settings_form %}
   {{set_form}}
</form>
```

I want the form to be displayed on all of the pages that this layout.html is extended to so sending it from a view is out of the question.

I keep hearing about RequestContext but I don't know how to render it using that. If you know please describe where should I create this new file for this function to be implemented and how should I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After help from a known friend I tried using context_processors, I added the form into context_processors by creating a `context.py` file in `app` and writing a simple 2 line code

```
def settings_form(request):
    return {'set_form': UserSettingsForm()}
```

and then adding `app.context.settings_form` to the context_processors in settings.
Now i'm able to render the form with ease. Took a lot of time to understand just a 2 line code. Python really makes it easier than I thought.